# NHibernate GroupBy error

Tags: linq, nhibernate, json.net

Good morning

I am pulling my hair on a simple linq query used for building a json:

```
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        JObject myJSON = new JObject();
        var result = new
        {
            test = from e in myTable
                   group e by new { e.col1, e.col2 } into g
                      select new
                      {
                          Code = g.Key.col1,
                          Name = g.Key.col2,
                          data = from e in myTable
                                 where e.col1== g.Key.col1
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     myField= e.field1
                                 }
                      }

        };
        myJSON = JObject.FromObject(result, serializer);
```

When i tried that i got a:

```
    System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
        at             NHibernate.Linq.GroupBy.NonAggregatingGroupByRewriter.FlattenSubQuery(SubQueryExpression subQueryExpression, QueryModel queryModel).
```

My linq query does not look that complicated but i have exhausted all my attempts.

Your lights on that would be welcome.

Thanks
Sylvain

Answer (score -2):

OK, finally found it. Just had to do the following:

```
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    JObject myJSON = new JObject();
    var result = new
    {
        test = from e in myTable.ToList()
               group e by new { e.col1, e.col2 } into g
                  select new
                  {
                      Code = g.Key.col1,
                      Name = g.Key.col2,
                      data = from e in myTable
                             where e.col1== g.Key.col1
                             select new
                             {
                                 myField= e.field1
                             }
                  }

    };
    myJSON = JObject.FromObject(result, serializer);
```

with a .ToList() on the first query.

Sylvain

Comment: myTable.ToList() => gets you all table and then you do a group locally instead of to make it to do the server